# Remove link from PHP title

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the link from this so it's only a H1 title but I dont really know what to remove exactly

```
<h1 class="ttu">
    <a href="<?php $cat = get_term_by('name', single_cat_title('',false), 'product_cat'); echo get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Our Collections' ) ).$cat->slug;?>" id=""><?php single_cat_title();?></a>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go

```
<h1 class="ttu">
    <?php single_cat_title();?>
</h1>
```